# VBA open a csv file with unknow file name

Tags: vba, csv, path, filenames

I have got a rather simple question as i think but i couldnt find out it myself.

I want to open a csv File in a defined binder but with an unknow filename. I would asume that it should work with simply "path/*.csv" however it is not :(  The errormessage says "Wrong Filename". Do i need to use something else in VBA.

```
path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\input\"
Open path & "*.csv" For Binary As #1
```

The above code does not work for me :( The CSV is called xyz.csv

```
path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\input\"
Open path & "xyz.csv" For Binary As #1
```

The code above is working however i have fix added the csv filename, which in this case is xyz.

Somebudy knows how to get that thing to work?

Cheers and thx for your time

Marc

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim path As String
Dim csvFiles As String
path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\input\"
csvFiles = Dir(path & "*.csv")

Do While Len(csvFiles) > 0
  Debug.Print csvFiles
  csvFiles = Dir
Loop
```

You can use the Dir() Function to check the files in your folder if you don't know the filename.